# Can I provide users with the option or feature to withdraw virtual currency in App?

Tags: google-play-services, in-app-billing

Does google play allow apps to provide users with the option or feature to withdraw virtual currency from an in-app wallet? I have read through google policy center payment part(https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738?hl=en&ref_topic=9857752&sjid=1909511748429591321-AP) and in point number 5 it says: "In-app virtual currencies must only be used within the app or game title for which they were purchased.” So we knew that the in-app wallet will allow the purchase of a digital product or service in the app. But what about users withdrawing the virtual currencies from the in-app wallet?

I'm creating an app that allows users to use in-app-purchases to buy virtual currencies(coin) for an in-app wallet. These virtual currencies allow users to buy an in-app product, and also provides users with the ability to submit applications to apply to withdraw virtual currencies. Based on this design, am I allowed to use google app billing system service in my app?